# Does EventHubProducerClient offer SendAsync with single EventData?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-eventhub

It seems from the official documentation that they only support sending batch.
Just curious to know if something exists (other than sending one as a list of course)

Comment: Why not use an `EventHubClient`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.eventhubs.eventhubclient.sendasync?view=azure-dotnet You can send a single event or a batch of events

Comment: `EventHubClient` belongs to the legacy `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs` SDK;  we recommend using `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs` for new development.

Comment: What in the... I had no idea there was a new SDK.

Comment: Yeah, we snuck that in a little ways back as part of the efforts to improve the Azure developer experience and drive a consistent approach to organization, naming, and API structure across each of the services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `EventHubProduerClient` does not offer a means to send a single event.  During design of the new SDK, we learned that many of the developers using the the single event overload were doing so in scenarios where it had a negative impact on the performance and throughput of their application.

The legacy overload simply performed an implicit `new[] { yourEvent }` and called into the `IEnumerable<EventData>` overload, causing an allocation and network call for the one event.  A fairly large portion of the developers using it let us know that they had assumed there were optimizations within the client to implicitly group events into batch and publish them in an efficient manner.

We removed that overload to reflect the actual behavior and raise developer awareness, hopefully helping to encourage consideration of the best pattern for the scenario.

At some point, we'd like to bring back an optimized version single event publishing, but I can't yet say what form that will take or what the timing may be.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Jesse. Makes Sense!! Somehow we are bound to add EventData in a sequential manner so were looking for options, will go ahead with new[] {} for now.

Comment: I'd be cautious with that approach if sequencing is important.  It is entirely possible for parallel `SendAsync` calls to complete out-of-order, as with any network request.   It would probably be safer to build up a batch or a list/array of events and send them in a single call.   The client will preserve ordering within the scope of the batch or enumerable.   Of course, if you're only ever making a single `SendAsync` call, and you're not concerned about the performance cost, your approach is just fine.